# Mechanical general knowledge questions

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I’ve been working through some general knowledge mechanical theory questions and there aren’t any answers to check if I’m correct.

Can you tell me if I’m correct please? Also, I’m confused about what image 3 is even showing- can someone clarify this for me? Thanks

SOURCE:https://talentcentral.eu.shl.com/player/workflow/start

[image]

[

[image]

[image]

Comment: no yes no .....

Comment: Site policy requires that you attribute those screenshots to their creators. Provide links.

Comment: Done added a link. Also, why is the first no please? It doesn’t mention mass or friction, so they all roll at the same speed?

Comment: moments of inertia.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like the sort of [check-my-work question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/335/1832) that isn't a good fit for this site. Such questions are usually deemed acceptable only if they involve doubts on specific ideas or concepts behind the problem, not the math. If there is some specific concept which you think you may not understand and which may be the root-cause of your doubt, please [edit] your question accordingly.